# Selecting element inside of shadow root using css

Tags: css, shadow-root

I want to fix some styling of a component which I'm importing. The component uses its own shadow root (I think), and inside of that shadow root is the div I want to add some styling to.

Now I've tried using :host(), and :host-context(), but for some reason it's not being selected. When I select the custom element itself, it does add some styling. However, I don't want to add styling to the custom element, but to an element inside of it.

Below is a screenshot of the custom element, folded open in the inspector in Chrome:

[image]

I want to add some styling to the div with class .mb-1. Does anyone know which selector I should use?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this for while, there are a nice explanation about here:

[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

As you, i'd like this feature, but isn't available.